# Page won't render even if it's called

Tags: node.js, express, server, routes

I want to do a login page in node express. After checking the password and the username the page request the information fr the next page, but the page doesn't load.

With a post request i send the password and username to server and check it:

```
 router.post('/',function(req, res, next) {
  dbs.executeQuery("select Id from Admin where username=\"" +username+"\" 
  and password=\""+password+"\"",
  (err,data)=>{
    if (!err &&  data.length != 0){ 
        req.method = "GET";
        req.url = "/menu";
        router.handle(req,res,next);
    }
    else{
        console.log("error");
  })
 })
```

Here the query will be executed but won't render the index.ejs:

```
router.get("/menu", function(req, res, next) {
  dbs.executeQuery("select * from Menu", (err, data) => {
    if (!err) {
      obj = { print: data };
      res.render("index", obj);
    } else {
      console.log("Cant find data");
      res.render("index", { print: {} });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: any error logged ?

Comment: @candybeer nope :(

Comment: can you say more about your database, which db are you using ?

Comment: @candybeer mysql. But that shouldn't affect, in my knowledge, how the code works. The query is executed succesfully

Comment: Yes as db, i would like to say wich orm... ?

Comment: @candybeer i am not using, i just make the queries directly

Answer (score 0):

Maybe should you try with a redirect method :

```
 router.post('/',function(req, res, next) {
  dbs.executeQuery("select Id from Admin where username=\"" +username+"\" 
  and password=\""+password+"\"",
  (err,data)=>{
    if (!err &&  data.length != 0){ 
        res.redirect('/menu');           // <---- HERE
    }
    else{
        console.log("error");
  })
 })
```